# What is the difference between these two uses of const in C++?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the difference between const int*,  const int * const, int const *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-int-const)

What is the difference between

```
A const * pa2 = pa1;
```

and

```
A * const pa2 = pa1;
```

(I have some class A for example).

Comment: Duplicate of [what is the difference between const int*,  const int * const, int const *](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-int-const) (I knew this had been asked before, it just took me a while to find it :-P)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the type from right to left:

```
A const * pa2 = pa1;
```

`pa2` is a pointer to a read-only A (the object may not be changed through the pointer)

```
A * const pa2 = pa1;
```

`pa2` is a read-only pointer to A (the pointer may not be changed)

This does not mean that A cannot change (or is actually constant) const is misleading, understand it always as read-only. Other aliased pointers might modify A.

Answer (score 3):

```
A const * pa2
```

This is a non-const pointer to a const A.  You can change where the pointer points but you can't change the object pointed to by the pointer.

```
A * const pa2
```

This is a const pointer to a non-const A.  You can't change where the pointer points but you can change the object pointed to by the pointer.

```
A const * const pa2
```

This is a const pointer to a const A.  You can't change where the pointer points and you can't change the object pointed to by the pointer.

You may find the ["Clockwise/Spiral Rule"](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) helpful when trying to decipher declarations in C and C++.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the first is a pointer to a const object, which (loosely) means the object can't be change.

The second is a const pointer to an object, which means the **pointer** itself can not be changed (ie assigned to a different object).